# Is there a way to disable GPU for CPU pods?

Tags: kubernetes, gpu

I am running a GPU server by referring to [this document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-gpus/scheduling-gpus/).
I have found that GPU is used in DL work with Jupyter notebook by creating a virtual environment of CPU pod on the GPU node as shown below.

Obviously there is no `nvidia.com/GPU` entry in Limits, Requests,
so I don't understand that GPU is used.

```
Limits:
cpu: 2
memory: 2000Mi
Requests:
cpu: 2
memory: 2000Mi
```

Is there a way to disable GPU for CPU pods?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this topic](https://github.com/NVIDIA/k8s-device-plugin/issues/146) on github:

> This is currently not supported and we don't really have a plan to support it.

But...

> you might want to take a look at the CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES environment variable that controls what devices a specific CUDA process can see:
> https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cuda-pro-tip-control-gpu-visibility-cuda_visible_devices/